# Add two natural numbers

Tags: code-golf, integer

Given two natural numbers (less than 100) as input print the sequence of intermediate results obtained when computing the sum of the two numbers using only the following operations<sup>1</sup>:

- `n <-> (m+1)` for integers `n`and `m` satisfying that equation
- `(a+b)+c <-> a+(b+c)` for integers `a`,`b` and `c` (associative law)

*You are **not** allowed to use the commutative law (swapping the arguments of `+`)*

### Example

```python
5+3           # Input
5+(2+1)       # 3 = 2+1
(5+2)+1       # Associative law
(5+(1+1))+1   # 2 = 1+1
((5+1)+1)+1   # Associative law
(6+1)+1       # 5+1 = 6
7+1           # 6+1 = 7
8             # 7+1 = 8
```

### Rules

- Input: two natural numbers (positive integers)
- Output list of all intermediate steps in the calculation of the sum (using the rules defined above), you may omit the final result
- The expressions can be output in any reasonable format (the left and right operands of each `+` should be clearly determinable)
- You can choose the order in which the operations are applied as long as you reach the final result
- Each expression in the output has to be obtained from the previous expression by applying **exactly one** allowed operation to the previous operation
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest code wins

### Test cases

infix notation:

```
2+2 -> 2+(1+1) -> (2+1)+1 -> 3+1 -> 4
3+1 -> 4
1+3 -> 1+(2+1) -> 1+((1+1)+1) -> (1+(1+1))+1 -> ((1+1)+1)+1 -> (2+1)+1 -> 3+1 -> 4
1+3 -> 1+(2+1) -> (1+2)+1     -> (1+(1+1))+1 -> ((1+1)+1)+1 -> (2+1)+1 -> 3+1 -> 4
5+3 -> 5+(2+1) -> (5+2)+1     -> (5+(1+1))+1 -> ((5+1)+1)+1 -> (6+1)+1 -> 7+1 -> 8
```

postfix notation:

```
 2 2+ -> 2 1 1++ -> 2 1+ 1+ -> 3 1+ -> 4
 3 1+ -> 4
 1 3+ -> 1 2 1++ -> 1 1 1+ 1++ -> 1 1 1++ 1+ -> 1 1+ 1+ 1+ -> 2 1+ 1+ -> 3 1+ -> 4
 1 3+ -> 1 2 1++ -> 1 2+ 1+    -> 1 1 1++ 1+ -> 1 1+ 1+ 1+ -> 2 1+ 1+ -> 3 1+ -> 4
 5 3+ -> 5 2 1++ -> 5 2+ 1+    -> 5 1 1++ 1+ -> 5 1+ 1+ 1+ -> 6 1+ 1+ -> 7 1+ -> 8
```

[Example implementation](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBBCsMgEEXJNqdwaaiBSCmUggHPIe6qiRDSkBhaz9JNNs2heprOGEvajc48589857kOwbe3flles7fl-Z1lV2NJQ2VxyQlxlvgwGCoV14UQrvdII0dU8y0lMRMKz5IzriM13S6v_uRQL5AdeCqczN6o0qLZFPnvkxRKIWU4BO4UcI3DRuPnsScyR_OWPliI9kEDIRbcW9eZZAacdG5KVoYRXAFLM_Dj2yZWS0_smJLvej4)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The operations are based on the [formal definition of additon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Addition) but modified to work without the concept of a successor function.

Comment: Does this challenge fit in [tag:expression-building]?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... Should I delete my attempt? [See here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266725/120216)

Comment: @Tobias321 Yes, you can undelete it once you have found time to fix your solution

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
FṖ.ịoƲ€2¦ṁ¥,/ƭ$ƬṪ§Ƭ;@Ɗ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of positive integers and yields a list of nested lists representing (much like the [reference implementation](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBBCsMgEEXJNqdwaaiBSCmUggHPIe6qiRDSkBhaz9JNNs2heprOGEvajc48589857kOwbe3flles7fl-Z1lV2NJQ2VxyQlxlvgwGCoV14UQrvdII0dU8y0lMRMKz5IzriM13S6v_uRQL5AdeCqczN6o0qLZFPnvkxRKIWU4BO4UcI3DRuPnsScyR_OWPliI9kEDIRbcW9eZZAacdG5KVoYRXAFLM_Dj2yZWS0_smJLvej4)) one way to perform their sum.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t4c5peg93d@cf2/SoaY3RoWUPdzYeWqqjf2ytyrE1D3euOrT82Bprh2Nd/w@3H530cOcMoKLI/9GmOgrmsVwgKtpMR8EwFsgGccxiQRwIG4SBElABEM8UzEESiDaBK4GJgoRN4CLIotHGKIrhUiA5YxRhFKloIwxtCHmQAiMMOVT5aEOsBiApgvgUF4YqMsMvb45TygKbqCWagKEBgmMIdvB/Y1MdcwA)**

#### How?

```
FṖ.ịoƲ€2¦ṁ¥,/ƭ$ƬṪ§Ƭ;@Ɗ - Link: pair of positive integers, A = [n, m]
               Ƭ       - starting with X=A collect up while distinct under:
              $        -   last two links as a monad - f(X):
F                      -     flatten X
             ƭ         -     alternate between:
          ¥            -     (1) last two links as a dyad - F(Flat_X, X):
      €2¦              -           apply to second element, V, of X:
     Ʋ                 -             last four links as a monad - f(V):
 Ṗ                     -               pop -> [1 .. V-1]        or [] if V == 1
  .                    -               0.5
   ị                   -               index into -> [V-1, 1]   or [] if V == 1
    o                  -               logical OR V -> [V-1, 1] or  V if V == 1
            /          -     (2) reduce Flat_X by:
           ,           -           pair -> ...[[[[a,b],c],d],...]
                     Ɗ - last three links as a monad - f(StepsSoFar):
                Ṫ      -   tail -> removes and yields PreviousStep
                  Ƭ    -   starting with PreviousStep collect up while distinct under:
                 §     -     sums
                   ;@  -   append to the tailed StepsSoFar
```

---

Seems like the sums (`§`) could be performed within the first collect-loop (`Ƭ`), but I've not figured out a good way to do so...

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 98 bytes

```python
f=lambda m,n:[f"{m}+{n}"]+([n:=n-1]*n and[f"{m}+({n}+1)",*(f"({x})+1"for x in f(m,n)),f"{m+n}+1"])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3k9JscxJzk1ISFXJ18qyi05Sqc2u1q_NqlWK1NaLzrGzzdA1jtfIUEvNSoHIaQEltQ00lHS2NNCWN6opaTW1DpbT8IoUKhcw8hTQNoDGamjogtdoghUqxmlCbzAuKMvNKNNI0jHSMNDW5YDxDHWMknrGOIRLPFCQH0Q5zMAA)

-1 thanks to @STerliakov

#### Original [Python](https://www.python.org), 100 bytes

```python
f=lambda m,n:[f"{m}+{n}"]+(n-1and[f"{m}+({n-1}+1)",*(f"({x})+1"for x in f(m,n-1)),f"{m+n-1}+1"]or[])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3U9JscxJzk1ISFXJ18qyi05Sqc2u1q_NqlWK1NfJ0DRPzUqBiGtVAbq22oaaSjpZGmpJGdUWtprahUlp-kUKFQmaeQpoG0ABdQ01NHZB6bYhipdj8ouhYTahd5gVFmXklGmkaRjpGmppcMJ6hjjESz1jHEIlnCpKDaIc5GQA)

Outputs a list of strings in infix notation.

Comment: [99](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY5BCoMwEEX3PUXIaqYZF1FKi-BJxIWtDBWaUSSCJeQk3bhp79TbFKmCy8f7n_9fn_7p753M83v0nFy-Ny4etbs2tXIkeck6uGiCRF0ZAJ8XklispVkFBB-NRU1HYA1himis5m5Qk2pFMTjyiLRkzRLUVTeUFa5T535oxQNDSiniYSNL2Y4ysjs6Le5f3x7_AA) by extracting `n-1` into variable

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 64 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＦ⊖ηＥ²⪫⟦×(ιθ+×(κＩ⁻η⁺ικ×+1)κ×)+1ι⟧ω⮌Ｅη⪫⟦×(ι⁻⁺θη⊕ι+1×)+1ι⟧ωＩ⁺θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8/D4IwEMV3P8WFqQ11QOPEqAsmGmLcjAPimTZCgfLHj1@PQoBBp/bevb7fayoTkxZJZm2ky7Y5t/kDDat4uFrOkuZXYYAdMDWYo27wSSKH2CjdsFNSso2AY6E0u11VjjXzmCdAcQGVAM@n@0J@k7xPanqndFszKSDO6FT9hvPJ6gd8NI8C9wMXehfwIWO4GugX7NDU6FrIPy0GksNQIUlKpOefqJ7qufTfqInlas8xtLB2B1u77rIv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the two numbers.

```
Ｆ⊖ηＥ²⪫⟦×(ιθ+×(κＩ⁻η⁺ικ×+1)κ×)+1ι⟧ω
```

Output the steps that split the second number into units and associate them with the first number.

```
⮌Ｅη⪫⟦×(ι⁻⁺θη⊕ι+1×)+1ι⟧ω
```

Output the steps that add the units to the first number.

```
Ｉ⁺θη
```

Finish with the final sum.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

```javascript
x=>g=(y,a='',b=`
`)=>(--y?a+x+`+${y+1+b+a+x}+(${y}+1)`+b+g(y,'('+a,')+1'+b)+a:a)+x+++`+1${a?b:b+x}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvLCoMwEEbhvc8hZIZfC6GXhRB9lUysSouYUksxiM@ezrbLc@B7ylfW/v14feol3oc8ury5dnKUKnHGVMH5wrNrqa5TJ9jgUe4JFgFaB0jrgGWvY1JkyEAqw7AGgSGNsCIos@UuXWiCKp/7uKxxHk5znGikK9OZufifN6aLzvwD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 90 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`\+1(1+)(.*$)
$&¶$%`+($1+1)$2¶($%`+$1)+1$2
+`\(?(1+)\+1\)?(.*$)
$&¶$%`1$1$2
1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxDYQwEATzq2NBd6yEdLY@JvwmHBgJAhICRG0uwI357fDDHc3sc77XvbdJv7mlg4JFmBNdnabrAhPMtWDKVDjdEGrRMeFGRxi2bsPuUbLtr3EMw/vrOjdILS0wSKR3FuXD@AM) Link is to test suite that outputs all the test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`\+1(1+)(.*$)
$&¶$%`+($1+1)$2¶($%`+$1)+1$2
```

Repeatedly convert `x+<1y>` into `x+(y+1)` and then `(x+y)+1` until `y` is `1`.

```
+`\(?(1+)\+1\)?(.*$)
$&¶$%`1$1$2
```

Repeatedly convert `(x+1)` into `<1x>`.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>140</s> 137 bytes

```python
lambda x,y,a='',b='':(a+f"{x}+{y}{b}\n{a}{x}+({y-1}+1){b}\n{f(x,y-1,'('+a,b+')+1')}\n"if~-y else'')+a+f"{x+y-1}+1{b or chr(10)+str(x+y)}"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JY5BCsIwEEWvErqZCZOAQQQRvEk3iTa0UNuSRmgIce8Z3BREdx7I2xjJZj7zPv_zH-8p-HYc1qc91q-rt3L_vff6Ys6aLSIIfQQQJp8DarJVXBLFkKJJ9RB1-r8Yg1SJFC_QYo5JJQCBtDAEnBTw7FSdvcnAmn5uIMPSRiUbDRsdO7UO1YbT7B1mh6eqDPpMrhs8WtyJLeeFrWvRHw)

A port of [l4m2's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266689)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-lp`), 135 bytes

```perl
1while print,s/\+(?!1\b)\d+/"+(".($&-1)."+1)"/e||s/(\d+)\+\((\d+)\+(\d+)\)/($1+$2)+$3/||(s/^[^+\d]*\K(\d+)\+1\b/$1+1/e,s/\((\d+)\)/$1/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCsIwEETvfoWGILuu7bKt9eoH@AmuPUgDFkIbmoKXfLuxYj3NwLyZCW7yTc7yevbebcPUD/MxshJcdqIP1I7YEJgS7L4QLA0JGnYpRYYlQyWF1fwEGayQrZBszSlB5PbWknb3g15XcNnlhRF23yf496ww5txQvTnT6T2GuR@HmAsfPg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 153 bytes

```scala
def f(m:Int,n:Int):Seq[String]=n match{case 1=>Seq(s"$m+1");case _=>Seq(s"$m+$n")++Seq(s"$m+(${n-1}+1)")++f(m,n-1).map(x=>s"($x)+1")++Seq(s"${m+n-1}+1")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5NCsIwEIX3nmIIXWRIFGIRRKng0oUrlyISa-oPZqwmQqF4EHHTjZ7Ci3gbWxWRbmZ438x7M9e7i_VOh8Vjv9ia2MNYbwhM5g0tHQzTFPIGwO3kk2b3eVmaBBJueyPykqqKvYk5TCf-uKHVLCKw2sfrPNbOgIoG5Yw7FlihGPbfcP4HA2IoxE_yIKemOguFFS6vyFJiy-qUZ9HAMR5kWAX9LLkVHwPD8_fBEUBavuJ3xBPelm3Exj9RMqyRUKoa6bx3voFF8ekv)